# Schengen Visa Germany, sponsorship denied due to lack of "commitment form"

Tags: visa-refusals, germany, schengen-visas, thailand

My Thai partner recently attended an appointment for a Schengen visa at the German embassy in Bangkok.

Upon arriving and before submitting the application we were informed the application would be denied because I lack a commitment of sponsorship form that I apparently would have to obtain from the German embassy in the UK, a form that before the appointment I have found no reference to on shengen Visa advice websites.

In the application I (as a UK citizen) provided a sponsorship letter detailing my commitment to pay the costs and explaining the source of my funds. For supporting documents I included up to date bank statements (coving more than 6 months from today's date), proof of property ownership in the UK, a copy of my passport, and a fully booked (and paid for) itinerary for our trip to Europe.

We applied for and have had accepted a UK tourist visa having supplied much the same set documents.

I have evidence of considerably more than the recommended sufficient (£55x planned number of days) funds available going back long before the time period on my supplied bank statements.

We would be happy to adjust our itinerary to apply to a different Schengen country for the visa, ideally one we could apply to from within Thailand, countries which we are already planning to visit are: Germany, Czech Republic, Austria, Hungary, Romania.

If anybody has had experience with this situation could they suggest an alternative recourse for a Schengen visa application that would not require me to fly from Thailand to the the UK just to obtain a form?

Comment: The Embassy should offer you a **Verpflichtungserklärung**, which a standardised form and together with copies of your financial statements become part of the application. Fee € 29. Each copy will cost 0.5€ if they have to make the copies.

Comment: You should be able to apply for this in Bangkok according to the guidelines. It states **either** from inside Germany or the Embassy where the application is being made. From a 3rd country is not meantioned. Other Schengen Countries will probably know of this refusal, so try to clarify it at the German Embassy.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine why this legally binding form **cannot** be done in Bangkok, is that in the worst case scenario it cannot be inforced in the UK. If you have someone in the UK who can legally do this for you, that may be a option to avoid a round trip.

Comment: I do not have anyone in the UK who could legally represent me in this manner, we explicitly asked if we could obtain the form in the German embassy while we were there and we were informed by the member of staff that it must be done in the UK.

Comment: According to this site I must be a legal resident in Germany for the Verpflichtungserklärung. I am not. [germany-visa.org](https://www.germany-visa.org/verpflichtungserklarungen/)

Comment: Yes, see my comment below the false answer below. Assume it can only be made where the legal document can be inforced. That would be then the UK, since you don't seem to be a Thai resident. Your 'local' German authority would be a German consulate or embassy in the UK.

Comment: So the answer would be, short of me taking a round trip flight, she must find an alternative sponsor? Our plan is to ultimately fly to the UK together, however it is neigh impossible for her to apply for a shengen visa whilst there. Fortunately her parents do have the funds to act as a sponsor. The lack of transparency for the application process has been exceedingly frustrating.

Comment: @SamFH Your frustration is understandable. A constructive letter to the Embassy in London with 'had your site contained this clarification then.. ' might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** no, this must be applied for in your country of residence

---

The **Verpflichtungserklärung** is a legally binding declaration that the signer will cover all costs of a foreign national while in Germany

- this is mainly intended for German residents only

The Visa guidelines state this can also be used for travel visas

- which a consulate or embassy can issue

  - there is no **explicit** statement that the signer must be a resident of the country the consulate is responsible for

Based on the information given in the question and comments

- The United Kingdom resident was told by the Embassy in Bangkok

  - he must make the declaration in the United Kingdom

Probable explanation is that the declaration can only be inforced in the country of residence and **not** in a country of *temporary* residence (visiting).

Answer (score 0):

The commitment form is what the call obligation letter,you need to get it from your local authority in Germany showing that you are inviting someone from Thailand who will stay for a certain duration of time,then send it to your Thai Partner to take it to the Embassy,that way your partner will get the visa.it happened to me last year but got the visa after I send the obligation letter.

Comment: Being a UK citizen, living in the UK, he has **no** local authority in Germany (he is not a resident in Germany) to apply to.